# Ragel string matching

Tags: pattern-matching, ragel

I am trying to learn ragel for a project I am working on. I am new to this.

I have a list of 15 strings. The problem is to check if a given string matches any of this 15 strings.

Under normal circumstances building a hash set with the 15 strings is enough to do O(1) lookup for the string and tell if it matches or not.

In my case I will be doing this a billion times. So I am trying to build a state machine for these 15 strings using ragel and check if the given string matches.

I feel using the ragel approach is better as in both cases I will have to go through the characters one by one. i.e. In order to compute the hash we need to scan through all the characters once and then do a look up. Where as using state machines scanning through all the characters once gives the result and avoids doing the lookup.

Is this a better approach? And can any one point me to how to build state machines for 15 strings to do string matching?

Answer (score 0):

On some architectures, with a proper alignment, a hand-coded `*(int64_t*) "8 bytes" == *(int64_t*) a_c_string` comparison works best, because it uses a single CPU instruction to compare 7-8 bytes.

Ragel doesn't have that final hash-table lookup, but it has more [branches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_prediction), so whether it will be faster or slower - it depends. I invite you to try a perfect hash (something like [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/)), a fast general-purpose hash ([dense_hash_map](http://code.google.com/p/sparsehash/)) and Ragel and share the results.

Here is an example of a lookup table in Ragel:

```
// ragel -G2 -o table_ragel.cc table.cc
int table (const char* cstring, int len) {
  char *p = (char*) cstring, *pe = p + len; int cs; %%{ machine table;
    main := ('foo' % {return 1;} | 'bar' % {return 2;});
    write data; write init; write exec; }%%
  return 0;
}
int main() {
  printf ("id: %i\n", table ("foo", 3));  // Prints 1.
  printf ("id: %i\n", table ("bar", 3));  // Prints 2.
  printf ("id: %i\n", table ("", 0));  // Prints 0.
  return 0;
}
```